# To ask or not to ask (about calories)

Tags: discussion

Advice on these

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/how-to-determine-raw-caloric-need-when-backpacking

[Is there a straightforward way to calculate energy requirements for a trek](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/134/is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-calculate-energy-requirements-for-a-trek)

Should I ditch mine and try to provide a better answer to the other?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see how your question differs enough from the original to merit a separate question.  If you think it does, try to clearly and explicitly explain in your question what you are looking for that's not covered in the first. Otherwise I suggest you add a bounty to the original detailing what you are looking for that the existing answers don't cover.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!